# client_side_validations and callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, client-side-validation

I have a model with fields that are validated frontend with client side validations gem.

My problem is for the below field (European VAT number for France) :

```
validates :VAT, length: { maximum: 15 }
validates :VAT, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{0,13}\z/ }
```

Also I have this callback in order to normalize it before validation :

```
before_validation :normalize_vat

def normalize_vat
  if self.VAT.present?
      self.VAT[0]=self.VAT[0].capitalize
      self.VAT[1]=self.VAT[1].capitalize
      self.VAT = self.VAT.delete(' ')
  end
end
```

This callback capitalize letters and strips the spaces that a user could have input such as :

> FR 333 3333 333333

Though it seems client_side_validations is not picking the callback frontend...

I could change the regexp to match any spaced input but it wrecks a bit my validations as I can't validate length no more for example ...

Would there be a trick to fix this ?

Comment: what do you mean by "Though it seems client_side_validations is not picking the callback frontend..." ?

Comment: Well when I type FR 333 3333 333333 it doesn't pass. (without client_side_validations it would pass)

Comment: What validation error message are you getting?

Comment: in Console it does pass. In front end I get "too long" error. The normal way, the callback is taken in. With client _side_validations the callback is not taken into consideration. I am trying to find a trick to make it work